# Ejs file unable to read array variable

Tags: html, node.js, ejs

I've created a for loop to create a table of records when rendering an ejs page with an object(requested).
I want to create buttons that links each record to another page  based on their Ids from mongodb. To do this, I've stored each object _id to another array called venueID.
The problem I am facing now is that, the program is unable to read venueID[i] when I add it to a link like so :

```
<td> <button   onclick="location.href = `/dashboard/requests/details/${venueID[i]}`"
```

whenever I click on the button I get an error saying venueID is not defined.
Although I am able to output it on my console using console.log(venueID[i]).

How do i fix this?

Full code:

```
 <% var venueID=[]; %>
            <% for(var i=0; i<requested.length; i++) { %>

              <% venueID[i]=requested[i]._id %>

                <tr>
                      <td><%= venueID[i]%></td>
                      <td><%= requested[i].roomNo %> </td>   
                      <td><%= requested[i].requests.user.name %> </td>
                      <td><%= requested[i].requests.time%> </td>  
                      <td> <button   onclick="location.href = `/dashboard/requests/details/${venueID[i]}`">View Details</button> </td>


                </tr>
            <% } %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your onclick attribute this way.

```
<td> <button   onclick="location.href = `/dashboard/requests/details/<%= venueID[i] %>`">View Details</button> </td>
```

or use `requested` directly

```
<td> <button   onclick="location.href = `/dashboard/requests/details/<%= requested[i]._id %>`">View Details</button> </td>
```

Alternatively you can use `<a>` tag to navigate. For example:

```
<td><a href="/dashboard/requests/details/<%= requested[i]._id %>" > <button>View Details</button></a> </td>
```

Comment: opps, my bad!
Still new here haha.